# Trying to use Python and BeautifulSoup to extract exact value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi guys I have a piece of html page i need to parse.
So I need Name and Email address.

Last Name:

    *Email Address:*

So I tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page_data():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    email = soup.find(id='email')
    first = soup.find(id='name.first')
    data = {'first': first,
            'email': email
            }

 return data
```

And it gives me output:

```
{
    name:id="name.last" name="name.last" tabindex="2" type="text" value="**Name I need**"/>
    <br /> 
    email:id="email" name="email" tabindex="0" style="background-color:#D4D0C8;" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="**Email I need**" size="30" maxlength="50"/><br />
}
```

I tried to convert each to string and slice it. The output was:
name:value="**Name I need**",email:value="**Email I need**"

But it may not work for another pages.

Tried .next_sibling or previou_sibling but it return: None.

And I believe that there is more elegant way to do solve this.
Maybe with re or I missed smth from BeautifulSoup.

Will be happy for any advice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extracting attributes you need to call the attribute name after selecting the element.

```
def get_page_data():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    email = soup.find(id='email')
    first = soup.find(id='name.first')
    data = {'first': first['value'],
            'email': email['value']
            }

 return data
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!